# Zero knowledge? proof item association

Tags: cryptography

I'm a total noob when it comes to cryptography but I believe this falls under the "zero knowledge" category.

I have two associated pieces of information:

1. **tag** - Known by both parties. Unique per scenario.
2. **identity** - Known by only one party. Potentially associated to multiple tags. Comes from a pool known by both parties.

I need a way to prevent the party with the association to change the value of the identity. There are around one hundred concurrent associations per scenario. The pool of potential identities can be relatively small, even smaller than the number of tags.

The most primitive option would be to hash the tag and identity together but with such a small pool of potential identities I fear it would be trivial to brute force the hash...

During the scenario more and more of these associations will become public. At least at that point I should be able to confirm that the other party did not modify the association. I don't really have to confirm this before then because unrevealed associations are not relevant. I just need to prevent the knowing party to pick and choose on revealing.

Is such a thing even possible? How could it be done? How difficult would it be to implement?

Comment: Better asked at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't implement this yourself.
you have two parties, Alice and Bob. ALice as the (identity, tag) pair. Bob only has the tag.
Alice wants to prove to Bob she has an identity  in that pair that she did not change but she does not want to reveal that identity to BoB.

What you want is a ["Signature scheme with efficient protocols"](http://www.zurich.ibm.com/~jca/papers/camlys02b.pdf). I know of no API's that expose this functionality. However, these are widely used in anonymous credential systems that can be used for your purposes.

Thankfully, there are two systems that support this type of thing. One is IBM [Idemix](http://www.zurich.ibm.com/idemix/) which uses the above technique and is where you should look first. The other is Microsoft's [U-Prove](http://www.zurich.ibm.com/idemix/).